# How to set current user in Azure Blockchain workbench through REST API?

Tags: azure, blockchain, azure-rest-api, azure-blockchain-workbench

*I am new to Azure blockchain workbench*. I have created an application. Now I am trying to preform operations through `REST API`.  I can create users using `POST /api/v1/users`. I get the `userID` in response. I am also able to verify this using `GET /api/v1/users`.

But when I use the api `GET /api/v1/users/me` , I get the following response-

```
{
    "currentUser": {
        "userID": 4,
        "externalID": "c737863b-17d7-4d66-be78-7b3e1b9d66af",
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": "",
        "emailAddress": null,
        "userChainMappings": [
            {
                "userChainMappingID": 4,
                "userID": 4,
                "connectionID": 1,
                "chainIdentifier": "0x53ab468b227edef755cd77198da00eeab1d0ed09",
                "chainBalance": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "capabilities": {
        "canUploadApplication": true,
        "canUploadContractCode": true,
        "canModifyRoleAssignments": true,
        "canProvisionUser": true,
        "canUpgradeWorkbench": true
    }
}
```

I tried using this `external ID` to set the first name, last name, email. But I am still getting `NULL` here. How do I set the current user to the one that I have created through `API`?